# How do I connect outdoor security camera to a power source?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, security

[image]

IP Camera has an ethernet cable and a dc12 cable that came with power adapter that plugs into outlet. Where the camera is going to be placed, there is a lamp nearby and power cables going into it, how can I get power from it and into camera? My other choice is a nearby outlet, but don't know how either. The dc12 cable, how can it be joined into normal home electric wires?

Comment: Did you not get a power supply with your camera?

Comment: Exactly why I love POE.  Sounds like you have everything you need, do you just need to extend the 12v power cord?

Comment: I got power supply with it, but if I use it, plug it into outlet under camera, won't it look weird? And it's not weather proof? I have no idea how any of this connects. It sounds like I have two options, ethernet or the 12v supply.

Answer (score 6):

### Power cord method

1. Have an electrician install a power receptacle within cord's reach of the camera
2. Route cord from camera to receptacke
3. Plug cord into camera
4. Plug power block into receptacle

### Extension power cord method

1. Get a 12VDC extension cable with the right ends on it.
2. Run the extension cable with the ethernet cable, follow rules for Class II low voltage wiring
3. At the hub/switch end of the ethernet run, plug factory power block cable into extension cable
4. Plug power block into wall

### PoE method (Power on Ethernet)

1. Return these/sell on Craigslist and get PoE cameras, or, get PoE extractors for this camera.
2. Run just ethernet cable to your router/hub.
3. Install PoE switch/hub as extension of, or to replace, your router
4. Plug ethernet cable into PoE hub

Comment: I don't understand "Extension power cord method". Why should I run ethernet cable if I have no ethernet? What is meant by "At the hub/switch end of the ethernet run, plug factory power block cable into extension cable"? I can't get ethernet cable to router, as router is in far away room. I can maybe get it to telephone jack, but that's useless.

Comment: I don't understand then, from your description the camera also requires ethernet.  Since you didn't ask "how do I get ethernet and power to this camera", I assumed you had ethernet managed.  Is that not so?  Is it a wireless camera?

Comment: It's a wifi camera but I haven't tried it yet, because I have no ethernet to router. For power, I have two outlets nearby, closet is a door bell but I rather not use, and other outlet is also reachable enough for someone to tamper with. My other choice is use the same electrical wires that go into an overhead lamp. This is the camera: DS-2CD2020F-IW

Comment: Sounds like a new receptacle is called for.  I would have the electrician install the receptacle somewhere vandals can't reach any easier than reaching the camera itself.

Comment: so i can have a kind of portable receptable (raised  receptacle, no junction box) near camera, and use the power adapter plugged into it? Is that normal? Wouldnt it not be waterproof? should i have electrician do it, or someone who specializes in security cameras?

Comment: It depends on codes in your country, but in my country, codes would require a junction box and an in-use weather cover.   I would have him install it to code.  This is how $50 projects become $300 projects.  :) Honestly you may end up needing to run ethernet anyway; wifi doesn't necessarily go through exterior walls very well, that varies by building construction.  Maybe you can temporarily hook up power with an extension cord and test WiFi reception, because if the wifi isn't reliable you'll need to run ethernet anyway... and at that point, look at one of the other solutions.

Comment: There aren't any codes, it's third world country. Junction boxes aren't used here always, there is a black round receptacle glued or screwed into a wall that I see here, that acts like an outlet for a quick job. I will test wifi, does signal need to be strong? Is wifi camera gave better range than smartphones?

Answer (score 1):

The only truly wireless cameras are battery operated, this camera is not wireless just because it can use wifi.

This camera is PoE capable, meaning you'll be able to power it over the ethernet network cable.  So you can get power to it over either a 12V power cord or an ethernet cable.

If you go with PoE, you have to run the cable all the way to your nearest switch / router, and you'll need a PoE injector, unless your switch is already PoE capable.

If you go with 12V power, you'll need to install a transformer - could be a plug in type, aka "wall wart" to the nearest receptacle, then run 12V power to the camera, and terminate with the correct size power connector to fit the cameras power cable.

Comment: my one router is in a far away room with no ethernet to it, but can i have a second router and bring it close to camera? for 12v, i dont understand why i cant just join the cables with houses electrical wiring, do i really need the power adapter that came with the camera? Is the transformer like the power adapter, or is it a type of receptacle?

Comment: The house wiring is 120VAC / 240VAC, the camera has accepts 12V supply - the power supply / transformer takes the 120V supply and gives you 12V with which to feed the camera.  If you supply the camera with 120V directly, it will be destroyed.  You have to be very careful to follow codes etc. working with 120V, with 12V there is far less hazard and greatly relaxed code rules etc.

Comment: So I have to use power adapter then, how is that supposed to look on a ceiling, any examples?

Comment: @altoban Not sure what you're asking - the power wire could be surface mounted, stapled or otherwise fixed to the ceiling;  it could be fished in the ceiling, usually that's challenging...

Comment: What i meant was, if a burglar came and saw the camera plugged into a socket, wouldnt he be like just unplug it?

Comment: Yes, hopefully you'd get footage of him unplugging it.  A burglar could also cut the wire, put a bag over the camera, spray paint the lens, or smash the camera with a hammer.